# "duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzf.class" cannot build apk

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task `':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'`.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzf.class

Comment: Pleas add a screenshot of your gradle build .

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between the **play-services versions** being used in your packages (i.e. a package using version x, another package using version y).

You can check which version of play-services your project is using with

**`./gradlew :app:dependencies`**

You will get an output similar to

```
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.2.6 --> (11.0.1)(*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.0.1 (*)
```

```

From this output you can see the **latest version of play-services** being used in your project (in the above example it's 11.0.1).

In your **`build.gradle`** file, you should specify this version for all play-services (they must all use the same version).