# Duplicate entry while adding firebaseui and firebase libraries

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, firebaseui

> check my gradle file for the above error,above error comes while 
>         generating signin apk`'
>
> duplicate entry: 
>            ``com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/zzc.class

check my gradle whether it is correct or is there any error in it

I have facing the issue while generating signin apk
Is there any error in any dependencies ?

Check my gradle whether it is correct or is there any error in it.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


 android {
  compileSdkVersion 24
  buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
  publishNonDefault true

 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "itsolutions.insta"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
  }
  configurations {
  all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v7-appcompat'
  }

  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
  }


  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
        'proguard-rules.pro'

    }

  }

 }

 dependencies {
 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
 exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
 })

 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
 compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.0.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.2'
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
 compile files('libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar')
 }

 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Provide com.google.gms.google-services version

Comment: did you check this link? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41021286/duplicate-entry-com-google-android-gms-auth-api-signin-internal-zzf-class

Comment: And also check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437717/duplicate-entry-com-google-android-gms-auth-api-signin-internal-zzf-class-can

Comment: Check the compatibility of firebase ui and Firebase version: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

Answer (score 0):

Those configuration could be the reason .

```
compile files('libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar')

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'

configurations {
  all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v7-appcompat'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove any one of below library from you build.gradle:

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
 compile files('libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line of code:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.0.1'
```

with

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [compatibility here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries):

```
FirebaseUI Version  Firebase/Play Services Version
2.4.0               11.4.0
2.3.0               11.0.4
2.2.0               11.0.4
2.1.1               11.0.2
2.0.1               11.0.1
1.2.0               10.2.0
1.1.1               10.0.0 or 10.0.1
1.0.1               10.0.0 or 10.0.1
```

**You have to change your dependencies according to this table:**

Change:

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
 compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.0.1'
```

In:

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
 compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.1.1'
```

Also check the **version of support libraries** related to firebase **11.0.2**.
It uses the support libraries **v.25.2.0**

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
```

Finally remove this line:

```
compile files('libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar')
```